# how do i make a submit button link to another page but i have required attribute

Tags: javascript

Hello so I have a problem with submit button leading to another page.
I figured it out how to make it go to another page but it doesn't recognize the required attribute.

Does anyone have any ideas ?

Html

```
<input type="submit" form="product_form" id="searchsubmit" onclick="myFunction()">
<form action="welcome.php" method="post" id="product_form">
<label>SKU</label> <input type="text" name="sku" class="sku" required>
</form>
```

JS

```
function myFunction() {
    window.location.href = "index.html";
}
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do? Why is the submit not inside the form? Why is the form action welcome but the submit action index.html? What is the required attribute and where is it needed?

Comment: Perhaps move the submit inside the form, remove the script and have welcome.php redirect to index.html

Comment: mplungjan is right, I placed your submit button inside the form and the validation is working

Comment: You should handle this redirection inside welcome.php. It is not making any sense the way you want to handle redirection.